# Resizing a label and Font of the form based on the window sizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize

I'm looking for help resizing a label's size and its font size based on its window size.

That's to say when a window resizes, the label itself adjusts it font and background box to do the same.

I know I'm triggering something on the Resize event of the form, but I don't know what. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in C# but it might help you.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
    label1.AutoSize = false;
    label1.Size = new Size(100, 50);
    label1.BackColor = Color.White;
}

void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Size = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width / 3, this.ClientSize.Height / 3);
    label1.Font = new Font("Arial", this.ClientSize.Height / 20);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A label is set to AutoSize by default, which should take care of itself (assuming that's what you mean by 'background box').

So, all you need to do is change the font based on the new size of the form. This should do it:

```
 private int _lastFormSize;
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bigger = GetArea(this.Size) > _lastFormSize;
            float scaleFactor = bigger ? 1.1f : 0.9f;
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily.Name, label1.Font.Size*scaleFactor);

            _lastFormSize = GetArea(this.Size);
        }

        private int GetArea(Size size)
        {
            return size.Height*size.Width;
        }
```

You would probably want to deterministically calculate the scale factor based on how much the area of the form has increased/decreased by, but that code should at least get you the effect.