# How to automatically scale child controls' font sizes when form size changes?

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel

I am using a TableLayoutPanel to contain controls that I would like to have automatically resize when the form is resized.  I would like to know how to make a form's child controls "scale" in size proportional to the form when the form itself is resized?  Although the TableLayoutPanel automatically adjusts the sizes of the contained controls, those controls keep the same font size.

Comment: Have you ever seen a program that makes its font smaller when the window gets smaller?   It is just not the way it is done.

Comment: The answer I posted works fine for my requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best method I have come up with so far.  I use two scale factors and I iterate through all the controls to selectively choose which ones I want to scale:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestTableLayoutPanel
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private const float LARGER_FONT_FACTOR = 1.5f;
        private const float SMALLER_FONT_FACTOR = 0.8f;

        private int _lastFormSize;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form2_Resize);
            _lastFormSize = GetFormArea(this.Size);
        }

        private int GetFormArea(Size size)
        {
            return size.Height * size.Width;
        }

        private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var bigger = GetFormArea(this.Size) > _lastFormSize;
            float scaleFactor = bigger ? LARGER_FONT_FACTOR : SMALLER_FONT_FACTOR;

            ResizeFont(this.Controls, scaleFactor);

            _lastFormSize = GetFormArea(this.Size);

        }

        private void ResizeFont(Control.ControlCollection coll, float scaleFactor)
        {
            foreach (Control c in coll)
            {
                if (c.HasChildren)
                {
                    ResizeFont(c.Controls, scaleFactor);
                }
                else
                {
                    //if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Label")
                    if (true)
                    {
                        // scale font
                        c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily.Name, c.Font.Size * scaleFactor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Big ups to Steven P for helping me formulate the answer to my question via his suggestion here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510577/resizing-a-label-and-font-of-the-form-based-on-the-window-sizing

Comment: I edited your post to fix the code format (it was split in two pieces).

Comment: Thanks!  I am not sure how it got split but at least it is fixed now.

Comment: Having tried this, note that it works well when using the minimize/maximize window buttons, but if one resizes the window by dragging the edge of the frame, the font scaling (for lack of a better word) explodes

Comment: test this sample and show lable out of form and labe in very big. not sync size between in form and lable

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answer, I wrote a real font scale solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MachineControlsTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        private int _lastFormSize;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form2_Resize);
            _lastFormSize = GetFormArea(this.Size);
        }

        private int GetFormArea(Size size)
        {
            return size.Height * size.Width;
        }

        private void Form2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;

            float scaleFactor = (float)GetFormArea(control.Size) / (float)_lastFormSize;

            ResizeFont(this.Controls, scaleFactor);

            _lastFormSize = GetFormArea(control.Size);

        }

        private void ResizeFont(Control.ControlCollection coll, float scaleFactor)
        {
            foreach (Control c in coll)
            {
                if (c.HasChildren)
                {
                    ResizeFont(c.Controls, scaleFactor);
                }
                else
                {
                    //if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Label")
                    if (true)
                    {
                        // scale font
                        c.Font = new Font(c.Font.FontFamily.Name, c.Font.Size * scaleFactor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```