# Scaling Components In Windows Forms For Different Size Monitors - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I am currently developing a windows form application to run on 4K monitors in Visual Basic. I am having trouble with scaling components, primarily text (labels). I developed the form of size 3840x2160 and an trying to keep the 'aspect ratio' or size of text the same with the rest of the form when migrating to different displays. There are thousands of labels and components thus manually setting them is not the best option. In Laymen's terms its almost as if I just wanted to 'stretch' the form as a picture and display this. The only method that I can get to work as intended is if I set The screens scaling to '225%'. I am hoping there is a more proper way of doing this so that I do not have to change the screens scaling.

From other posts:
I have added an App Manifest file and have tried different configurations with 'AutoScaleMode','AutoSize', and 'AutoSizeMode' properties.

Please let me know If there are any recommendations, I have went through many other posts and am still not finding something that works. Thank you!

Comment: There is a bit of info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 around resizing, auto scaling and dpi awareness  in windows forms

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I have read this document and still am not having any luck. My main issue is that my text is not scaling, or things with text such as Labels, checkboxes, radio buttons. Everything else is scaling appropriately, all panels, buttons (not text inside), and other controls are scaling as intended.  Any additional information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any built-in functionality that does this out-of-the-box.

A "hack" to do something like this with resizing the fonts to scale with your window size is to utilize the Form.Resize event, then use some calculation using the window's current height and width to set the font size of your controls.

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    label1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width / 3, Me.ClientSize.Height / 3)
    label1.Font = New Font("Arial", Me.ClientSize.Height / 20)
End Sub
```

This idea is not mine. I found it on [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510577/resizing-a-label-and-font-of-the-form-based-on-the-window-sizing).